# What's the difference between 「軽い」and 「身軽」?

Tags: words, word-usage, sentence

Hellow everyone!

I would like to know what's the difference between 「軽い」and 「身軽」? When is good to use each one? Could you give me an example?

Thank you!

Comment: You've tried some dictionaries, right? Please show what you've found so far, and tell us what you're confused with.

Comment: @Chocolate yes, I have tried. Both words are marked as "light". That's my confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have known「軽{かる}い」and 「身軽{みがる}」can both be translated as "light". However, they are used in different situations.

- 「軽{かる}い」is not so different from "light" in English and normally used to describe things have the nature of having little weight. It can be quantitatively measured by weighing scales.
- 「[身軽{みがる}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%BA%AB%E8%BB%BD-637293)」is, however, often used in a metaphorical sense or qualitatively. If you have measured having less weight than before, you feel you are moving more swiftly than before, you can say「動きが身軽{みがる}になった」or similar.
- In a metaphorical sense, you might say「金メダルの重責から解放されて身軽{みがる}になった。」: *"I feel relaxed now as I have been released from the pressure of winning the gold medal at Olympic Games"*. i.e. You are not saying that you physically weigh less than before, but rather that you do not feel the burden to be the best of the Olympic Games.

---

Interestingly, regarding the word「身軽{みがる}」, if you switched the「軽」: "light" to its antonym「重」: "heavy", it is [身重{みおも}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%BA%AB%E9%87%8D-637163) and it only means "pregnant", as far as I know. In other words, switching「軽」to「重」does not imply the opposite meaning i.e. you move slowly because of having lots of luggage or you feel the burden.